# Can vim treat a folded section as a motion?

Tags: vim, code-folding

I have a folded section in a text document. Can I use the fold as a *motion* in vim, in the same way a word or WORD is a motion with `w/W`?

For example `daw` deletes *around a word*, so

```
This is a |t|est
```

with the cursor in `||`, and in `normal` mode if I run the command `daw` will become

```
This is |a|
```

Can I do this with a folded section *(using `foldmethod=marker`, and latex code)*?

```
\begin{equa|t|ion}%{{{
a = 10
\end{equation}%}}}
```

after the *fold motion* would be deleted. Is this possible in other `foldmethod` modes?

*For my question I know I can just fold the section then delete the "line", but I was wondering if the fold itself can be treated as a motion.*

Comment: This would be a motion independent of whether the fold is folded or not

Comment: Did you try `daw` on a closed fold?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of such a thing in Vim. But one can use `[z` and `]z` to jump to the beginning and end of a fold.

This seems to do the trick:

```
xnoremap iz :<C-U>silent!normal![zV]z<CR>
onoremap iz :normal viz<CR>
```

You can use it like `iw` and friends:

```
ciz
diz
viz
yiz
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [vim-textobj-fold](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-fold) plugin. It provides text objects for foldings, which I think is exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Linking this here since I found it useful:

https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/10cqgd/looking_for_a_languageaware_block_selection/c6cpyrg

Short answer is you can do this:

```
" Create text objects using [z and ]z
vnoremap if :<C-U>silent!normal![zjV]zk<CR>
onoremap if :normal Vif<CR>
vnoremap af :<C-U>silent!normal![zV]z<CR>
onoremap af :normal Vaf<CR>
```

This gives you `if` and `af`, which work like `ip` and `ap`.